# Detroit airport to/from Auburn Hills public transportation?

Tags: trains, public-transport, buses, taxis, detroit

I am a student traveling from Houghton to Detroit by flight for an interview.
I do not have a driving license, so public transport is my only option.
I am staying in Auburn Hills and need to know what are the safe and economic options for traveling from and to the airport.

It seems that there is some bus transportation available, but I don't know what could be the pitfalls?
https://goo.gl/maps/Ccov1vZ2wWr

Comment: See also https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Detroit-Airport-DTW/Auburn-Hills

Comment: The only possible pitfall here is a 50 minute trip taking three hours at least but there's only one trip every hour so if you are less fortunate then close to 4. Also, it seems the last trip is at 3:26PM.

Comment: Does the hotel have an airport shuttle? Ask your host if they can arrange something (taxi, limo, whatnot) for you.

Comment: As I am not sure whether the company is going to reimburse me, I am on a tight budget. So I am choosing the DDOT bus option as it costs $5 while a taxi/Uber would cost about $50 just one way, so double that for return trip. I am also not staying in a hotel for the same reason, just found a place on Airbnb. So I will just walk to the interview from that place.

Comment: "I am not sure whether the company is going to reimburse me".  Why aren't you sure?  Did you ask them?